# encrypt and serialize by one --- deserialize and decrypt by another

Tags: java, encryption, serializable

I have serializable object:

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class ConfigObject implements Serializable{

private String url;
private String user;
private String pass;

public String getUrl() {
    return url;
}

public void setUrl(String url) {
    this.url = url;
}

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}

public void setUser(String user) {
    this.user = user;
}

public String getPass() {
    return pass;
}

public void setPass(String pass) {
    this.pass = pass;
}        
}
```

and 2 method in SerializableEncryptDecrypt class:

```
public static void encrypt(Serializable object, OutputStream ostream, byte[] keyy, String transformationnn) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        try {
            // Length is 16 byte
            SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(keyy, transformationnn);

            // Create cipher
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformationnn);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, sks);
            SealedObject sealedObject = new SealedObject(object, cipher);

            // Wrap the output stream
            CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(ostream, cipher);
            ObjectOutputStream outputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(cos);
            outputStream.writeObject(sealedObject);
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Object decrypt(InputStream istream, byte[] keyy, String transformationnn) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException {
        SecretKeySpec sks = new SecretKeySpec(keyy, transformationnn);
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(transformationnn);
        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, sks);

        CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(istream, cipher);
        ObjectInputStream inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(cipherInputStream);
        SealedObject sealedObject;
        try {
            sealedObject = (SealedObject) inputStream.readObject();
            return sealedObject.getObject(cipher);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I had made 2 softwares(soft1 and soft2) which use this class (`SerializableEncryptDecrypt`). That softwares encrypt and serialize input data(the same input data). when I compare the output data with the input which I give is totally different data. But I need the same output data.

thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It is a good practice to randomize encryption using some salt (nonce, IV, ...) so even if you encrypt with the same values with the same key, you may (and should) get different output. Having the same output lowers the security in some cases.

I cannot be sure, but I'd bet that's what the "SealedObject" does. If you really need "the same output", you could serialize the object directly (not using the SealedObject). But then - you are responsible for storing the salt, authentication tag, etc..

Please note - if you're using this code in some real project, you should not store the passwords (even encrypted), only their salted cryptographic hashes if neccessary.